# JQUERY GET operation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm having trouble with the following JQuery script

```
$('#extra_data').append('<div id="tabs-' + (tab_length + 1) + '"></div>');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#tabs-' + (tab_length + 1)).html(data);
     });
```

My trouble is that the $.get(..) operation doesn't return any results - although when using firebug it shows the ajax call as expected.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `url`?  Is it on the same domain as your page? If not, that's [the problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: The get method looks fine by me. Try alert(data); to see if there is indeed a result.

Comment: url contains the following string "/People/Index" - as this is an MVC application, "People" is the controller and "Index" the action (which returns a PartialView when called)

Comment: Is the Action (Index) actually getting called?

Comment: Hi Mark, The Index action gets fired every time and the partial view is returned as expected - i see this when debugging with firebug (and see my breakpoints in the action get hit).

Comment: If the Index action gets hit, then the Javascript code should work. Have you tried to isolate the problem by creating a simple HTML page with only the necessary Javascript code?

Comment: try this http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/ could be very helpful, it demonstrates a library with helpers for jquery popup, autocomplete and other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function GetPartialView() As ActionResult
    If (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) Then
        Return View("PVTest")
    Else
        Return View()
    End If
End Function
```

I've filtered the request if it is Ajax. You can even pass an object to your partial view.

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/GetPartialView',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('#extra_data').append(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Partial View (PVTest.ascx)

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<div id="01">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try load method:
$('#extra_data').append('');
$('#tabs-' + (tab_length + 1)).load(url)

Comment: i've tried this and get an ajax error with exception [object error].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Post and [HttpPost] in ASP.NET MVC, I think there is a security 
issue related to GET.

I only seem to use Post operations and remember seeing something about security.
Will see if I can verify that...

ADDED:

see: [ASP.NET MVC 2.0 JsonRequestBehavior Global Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663221/asp-net-mvc-2-0-jsonrequestbehavior-global-setting)

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work - still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a POST, as Mark suggested:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: { },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
    },
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    var Response = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

the Response should contain the JSON stream. You can append it to your element.

The controller should do something like this:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function DoSomething() As ActionResult

    Return (Json(myObject, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet))

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, My problem is that i'm returning a partial view - no objects are being passed to the view and as such, the use of JSON would simply not be suitable. Do you know how best i could tackle this problem with partial views in mind? (all i need is the html contained in the partial view to load into a tabbed control)

Comment: I guess your partialview is returned by a controller, right? Use the jQuery POST, anyway. That's the only way, unless you disable the security check. I've done something like that in a old MVC1 project. I'll try to attach some code.